# How to run Unsafe and Normal instance of Google Chrome at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am doing some web development and am serving some files locally. Now both Chrome and Firefox wont allow me this because of their origin policy. As I prefer Chrome, I chose to to use it in unsafe mode by adding the `--disable-web-security` flag.

While this works perfectly, there is a slight issue I am facing. I can't run the chrome instance in unsafe mode while my another chrome instance is running in normal mode. If I open new instance by opening the unsafe mode chrome shortcut whilst my regular instance is running, the new instance also opens in regular mode; and vice-versa.

Is there a way to open both simultaneously? If so, how do I achieve this?

PS: I will use two different browsers for this as my last option. I would like to avoid this as far as possible

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on a Linux SuperUSer forum at

https://superuser.com/questions/593726/is-it-possible-to-run-chrome-with-and-without-web-security-at-the-same-time

I earlier thought this could only be done in Linux but this is also possible in Windows. Essentially we are asking a chrome to create a new instance altogether than sharing the same instance. We do this by giving it a location to store it's data. You can read about this in the above shared link.